# why float become NaN

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2, j = 4;
    float b;
    
    b = j / i * i;
    
    printf("%f\n", j / i * i);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
-1.#QNAN0
4.000000
```

while this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2, j = 4;
    float b;
    
    b = j / i * i;
    
    printf("%f\n", b);
    printf("%f\n", j / i * i);
    return 0;
}
```

gives output

```
4.000000
4.000000
```

**why this is happening**

I try running it in vs code but the result is not as expected.

Comment: You need to cast j/i*i result  to float.

Comment: `j / i * i` is an `int` value but `%f` expects `float` or `double`.

Comment: Probably in your case floating point arguments are passed in FPU registers. So in second example UB turned out to printing "correct" (no) content of FPU register used in previous function call.

Comment: I agree there's the type error, but still odd. What operating system and compiler are you using? When I compile I get a warning that `j / i * i` is an `int`, but I don't get any `NaN`s (using macOS 13.4.1 with Apple clang version 14.0.3).

Comment: @MichaelM. because passing the wrong type for a format specifier is *undefined behaviour*, so what you get is what you get, not what someone else gets.

Comment: @CemPolat Applying a `float` cast as in `printf("%f\n", (float) (j / i * i));` is OK, yet then code goes through 2 casts, the explicit `int` to `float` (with possible loss of precision) and then the `float` to `double` as the result is passed as a `...` argument.  `printf("%f\n", (double) (j / i * i));` and `printf("%f\n", (double) j / i * i);` are better alternatives.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Answer (score 3):

> why float become NaN

The printed output does not indicate the *float* became [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) as the `printf()` was improper and invoked *undefined behavior* (UB).

- Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  A well enabled compile will complain about the mismatch.
- Match the print specifier with the argument type.  `"%f"` expects a `float` or `double` called with `printf()`.  As `i, j` are `int`, `j / i * i` is also an `int`.
  Using a mis-matched set results in *undefined behavior* (UB).  Anything may happen.  A common UB manifestation when FP and integer arguments are passed (in emitted code) in different ways to `printf()` and function ends up getting data from the wrong place (leftover from before) or uninitialized (`-1.#QNAN0`) values.
- "but the result is not as expected" --> When UB occurs, do not expect good results.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 2, j = 4;
    double b;
    
    b = j / i * i;
    
    // printf("%f\n", j / i * i);
    printf("%d\n", j / i * i);
    // or 
    printf("%f\n", (double) j / i * i);

    printf("%f\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Tip: `double` is often the best choice for a floating point type in C. Only use `float` when you have a compelling reason for it. [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77207869/why-float-become-nan#comment136111218_77207869)